# keystore password

Tags: password

how can get keystore password

```
"address":"95ee9edff131ebd460bddf2d2eeb3589564daed8",
"crypto":{
    "cipher":"aes-128-ctr",
    "ciphertext":"0b983fa1a3185fe9ee193a083588ec63e1e42bbcff89e343f5b88e082161dfd9",
    "cipherparams":{
        "iv":"97e9a57f5f7e0a7e7ddd7a168e8428bf"
    },
    "kdf":"scrypt",
    "kdfparams":{
        "dklen":32,
        "n":262144,
        "p":1,
        "r":8,
        "salt":"20bd5fa75f034eb2e5cd886f6ebe2fae2d8127f2e23250db8c7337f3fcb5a15f"
    },
    "mac":"33f9e2e107f705f7853ffa522042c24e5bf8c46554f1ae8541df6fb65957163f"
},
"id":"b7ff74b2-cbf5-4518-96b7-c3eeacd5904d",
"version":3
```

Answer (score 1):

This file doesn't contain your password. Rather, you *need* your password to make use of this.

The password is used to decrypt the account's private key.